# How to make human readable autoincrement column in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to make the column for store serial number of orders in the online shop.
Currently, I have this one

```
CREATE TABLE public.orders
(
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX orders_id_uindex ON public.orders (id);
```

But I need to create the special alphanumeric format for storing this number
like this **5CC806CF751A2**.

How can I create this format with Postgres capabilities?

Comment: Convert the ID to hex? But I wonder why a hex number is "more human readable" as a plain integer

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name because of it easier to remember

Answer (score 2):

You can create a view that simply converts the ID to a hex value:

```
create view readable_orders
as
select id, 
       to_hex(id) as readable_id,
       title
from orders;
```